# Excel - Conditional Formatting?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am working with a sheet that uses a dropdown to determine whether the data is shown in Revenue and Units.

I am wondering if there is a way to do a conditional format where when the dropdown is set to Revenue, it is shown in dollars?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select cell you want to format based on dropdown value
2. Go to conditional formatting -> new rule -> Use formula to determine which cells to format
3. If your drop down is in cell A1 it should say: =A1="Revenue" in this case
4. Select format and change to Accounting format with $ or whichever custom format you want on Number tab.[image]